# NPM Publish Error: You do not have permission to publish

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I do `npm publish` and goes through all the checks but then it returns the following\

```
48 error code E403
49 error 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.com/tictactoe - You do not have permission to publish "tictactoe". Are you logged in as the correct user?
50 error 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
50 error 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or
50 error 403 on a server you do not have access to.
```

So at first I do `npm whoami` and it returns `makashi` my username, So I know I'm logged in.

And my dependencies seem to fine, I am able to import them and import the package and run it fine.

```json
{
    "name": "tictactoe",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Simple Tic Tac Toe module to play with ease!",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "github.com/MakashiDev/tictactoe"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "tictactoe",
        "game",
        "fun"
    ],
    "author": "makashi",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
        "prompt-sync": "^4.2.0"
    }
}
```

There is my package.json everything seems normal and I cant find anything incorrect. I am very confused on this so please help figure this out.

Comment: [`tictactoe`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tictactoe) is owned by alexanderscott. What makes you think that **you** should have permission to publish a new version?

Comment: There are also [98 tictactoe related packages on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=tictactoe). Is it really worth adding another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TicTacToe is already taken as a package name. Use a different one.